# iMovie crashes on start up. How can I fix it?

Tags: macos, crash, imovie

iMovie version: 10.0.5

OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)

It crashed with these information:

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
```

And here is the thread-0  info

```
    Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903f9866 __pthread_kill + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9170135c pthread_kill + 92
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff935c8b1a abort + 125
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff914f5f31 abort_message + 257
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff9151b952 default_terminate_handler() + 264
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff9155f30d _objc_terminate() + 103
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff915191d1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff91519246 std::terminate() + 54
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff9155f0b0 objc_terminate + 9
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8a9142a1 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
    10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8a9141fc dispatch_once_f + 79
    11  com.apple.Motion.effect         0x00000001105f69c8 +[FFMotionEffect registerEffects] + 91
    12  com.apple.Flexo                 0x0000000107baccc7 +[FFEffect(RuntimeBundleLoading) _registerEffectsInBundle:atPath:] + 135
    13  com.apple.Flexo                 0x0000000107d5652d +[FFPluginDirectoryScanner _scanDirectory:withExtension:scanned:delegate:didLoadSelector:] + 653
    14  com.apple.Flexo                 0x0000000107d56991 +[FFPluginDirectoryScanner scanForPluginsInDirectory:withExtension:delegate:didLoadSelector:] + 961
    15  com.apple.Flexo                 0x0000000107bad0fc +[FFEffect(RuntimeBundleLoading) initEffectRegistry] + 284
    16  com.apple.Flexo                 0x0000000107bc30b5 FFInitializePart2 + 85
    17  com.apple.Flexo                 0x0000000107b98c86 +[Flexo finishInit] + 22
    18  com.apple.iMovieApp             0x000000010739cceb main + 1515
    19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff905f25fd start + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd> key and open iMovie. Than choose your library.iMovie should open now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this crash as well. Though I'm only seeing it when I try to capture iMovie and move it to another Mac in my lab via the Casper suite. I've had to delete and re-download it form the AppStore on each Mac.