# iMovie crashes on startup

Tags: crash, imovie

I've just installed iMovie from the App Store.  When I run it, it crashes after the Welcome wizard.  I've rebooted, deleted and reinstalled, and the same thing happens each time.

I've tried opening with Cmd and deleting preferences, I've deleted everything in ~/Movies, ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iMovieApp, it still crashes every time

> 2014 MBP, 16 GB RAM, just installed 10.13

There may be vestiges of old iMovie installs/projects laying around; if there are, I'm OK with completely deleting them, if someone can tell me how to hunt them all down

Crash report

> Process:               iMovie [1107] Path:
>   /Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/MacOS/iMovie Identifier:
>   com.apple.iMovieApp Version:               10.1.7 (310090) Build Info:
>   iMovieX-31009000019000000~1 App Item ID:           408981434 App
>   External ID:       823649006 Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:           iMovie [1107]
>   User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2017-10-01 19:33:44.776 -0500 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.13 (17A365) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
>   1BAD87A2-DB4E-312A-643C-36D1F4BE862D
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 2600 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        4  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   -[QCCGLRootContext minimalSharedContextForCurrentThread]: Inconsistent state abort() called HÇÆ±ˇ

Comment: Jason, does the info at this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/147619/168832) help?

Comment: yes, I saw that and tried those suggestions.  That post is 3 years old - not sure how much the app has changed since then

Comment: i also create a brand new account and tried running from there, same issue

Comment: From @hdp: Had this same issue when High Sierra first came out, Apple support talked me through SafeBoot (which I couldn't do because I use a firmware password) and opening iMovie in a new user account (which it did). After much fiddling around iMovie did work again, but I cannot say which part of the process made it work.

Today iMovie doesn't work again, could be that the 10.13 update has broken it again. Will post back if I find a fix that works for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have a MBP that does this. Are you running an external display mirrored with the lid closed? Mine works if I open imovie with the lid up.

Comment: Yeah, I found this out late last night.  I normally keep my MBP docked and use 2 external displays via the docking station.  I removed it from the dock and was able to get iMovie to work with the built in display.  Still, that's a pretty disappointing fix, all of my other apps work great when docked.

Comment: Same here. Come on Apple, you can do better than this.

Comment: 5 months later and the bug is still there... Apple software quality control is terrible these days...

Comment: I also had this problem and opening the docked MBP "solved" it.  I reported it to Apple Bug Reporter and they eventually got back to me and said the issue is a "DUPLICATE OF 32646813 (CLOSED)" and closed it.  But they refuse to provide information on whether or or how to resolve it.  "For security and privacy reasons, we don't provide access to the original bug yours was duped to."

Comment: My iMovie hung on startup - started without external display, and it opens. THANK YOU.

Comment: I had the exact same issue where I lost 3 hours installing/reinstalling and trying various other fixes. External display was the mere issue after all. I should’ve thought of the external display but for some reason it never occurred. Thanks a bunch for mentioning it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

With 10.13.2 it starts if you start it with lid open. After that you can close the lid or move the iMovie to external display.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue when High Sierra first came out, Apple support talked me through SafeBoot (which I couldn't do because I use a firmware password) and opening iMovie in a new user account (which it did). After much fiddling around iMovie did work again, but I cannot say which part of the process made it work.

Today iMovie doesn't work again, could be that the 10.13 update has broken it again. Will post back if I find a fix that works for me.

Comment: I am on 13.3.3 now, and in clamshell mode iMovie still quits on startup. If you open the laptop lid until the application has loaded all the clips you can shut the lid and continue in clamshell mode.